# Retrieve User Data to make leaderboards in Firebase iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create a leaderboard using Google Firebase Database and I have added my users and their scores into the Database successfully as shown in the picture below. I am trying to retrieve the data for Person 1 through Person 8 into an array in my code, and then from there I can sort them and add them to my leaderboard. I'm not sure though how I can retrieve the users and their scores systematically and without knowing their child name, as the users will enter their own names. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: Picture of my Firebase Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should retrieve/print the users in ascending order of score.

```
  usersRef.queryOrderedByValue().observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
      for child in snapshot.children {
          print((child as! DataSnapshot).key)
      }
  })
```

For me this prints:

> Person 4
>
> Person 1
>
> Person 2
>
> Person 3
>
> Person 5
>
> Person 7
>
> Person 6
>
> Person 8

For a leaderboard, you'll probably want to limit the number of users you retrieve:

```
_usersRef.queryOrderedByValue().queryLimited(toLast: 10).observe(.value) { snapshot in
  ...
```

This will just return the top 10 scores, still printing them in ascending order. To get them in descending order, you'll have to reverse them in the client.

Comment: thank you very much for your response. I had to tweak the code a bit to resolve a few errors that came up but the one I couldn't fix was "Ambiguous use of key". Do you know how I would fix that? Here is what I put in. Sorry if the formatting in a comment isn't great. 

```override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        rootRef.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                print((child as AnyObject).key)
            }
        })
    }```

Comment: It might have to be `child?.key`. I am never completely sure on Swift syntax there.

Comment: That didn't fix anything. I will do a little research and see if I can find something. Thank you anyway

Comment: I fixed the code to call the proper ordering method. I also updated it with the proper downcast.

Comment: The "as! DataSnapshot" fixed everything and it works as it should. I should be able to take it from here, but I'll be sure to come back if I have any more questions. Thank you so so much, you were a huge help!